# What is this item he is holding in this video?

Tags: hardware-identification

I was watching a YouTube video about DIY sofa upholstery. At [17:34](https://youtu.be/Wdy11hJX1-I?t=1052) the guy pulls out some sort of long metal plate with screw-like protrusions on one side.

[image]

I would like to be able to order (or make) one of those. So what are those called?

Comment: That link will be dead in an internet minute, making this Q&A useless for future visitors. You should find a picture of what you are talking about, or even provide a quick drawing and maybe a clearer description.

Comment: @jdv I've added the picture. A bit blurry, but I guess it would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seek is called an upholstery tack strip. The screw-like protrusions are barbs rather than screws and snag/catch the fabric to be stretched and secured.

A quick search using these terms return many results with varied prices and locations to purchase.

[image: tack strip image]